# fill only unique value from another dataframe based on condition

Tags: pandas, duplicates, unique

How to fill '0' value in df1 from unique value from another dataframe (df2). the expected output is no duplicate in df1.

any reference links for this. thank for helping out.

```
data1 = {'test' :['b',0,'e',0,0,'f']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)

data2 = {'test' :['a','b','c','d','e','f']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)
```

df1

```
   test
0   b  
1   0
2   e  
3   0  
4   0  
5   f
```

df2

```
   test
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   e
5   f
```

expected output:

```
   test
0   b  -- df1
1   a  -- fill with a from df2
2   e  -- df1
3   c  -- fill with c from df2
4   d  -- fill with d from df2
5   f  -- df1
```

Comment: Both dataframes are always going to be the same length?

Comment: yes it is, sammywemmy

Comment: Hi sammywemmy, if the dataframes are not always going to be same length, is there a solution for this? thank sammy

Comment: @stvlam22 my second solution should already work for this case ;)

Comment: my apologies. i didn't see below.. yes it worked thanks mozway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have enough unique values in `df2` to fill the 0s in `df1`, extract those unique values, and assign them with boolean indexing:

```
# which rows are 0?
m = df1['test'].eq(0)

# extract values of df2 that are not in df1
vals = df2.loc[~df2['test'].isin(df1['test']), 'test'].tolist()
# ['b', 'e', 'f']

# assign the values in the limit of the needed number
df1.loc[m, 'test'] = vals[:m.sum()]

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  test
0    b
1    a
2    e
3    c
4    d
5    f
```

If there is not always enough values in `df2` and you want to fill the first possible 0s:

```
m = df1['test'].eq(0)

vals = df2.loc[~df2['test'].isin(df1['test']), 'test'].unique()
# ['b', 'e', 'f']

m2 = m.cumsum().le(len(vals))

df1.loc[m&m2, 'test'] = vals[:m.sum()]

print(df1)
```

Comment: Thanks mozway. you always been helpful.. sorry for my late reply

Answer (score 1):

Solution Assumptions:

1. number of '0' == unique values in df2
2. have a column like 'test' to be manipulated

```py
# get the unique values in df1
uni = df1['test'].unique()

# get the unique values in df2 which are not in df1
unique_df2 = df2[~df2['test'].isin(uni)]

# get the index of all the '0' in df1 in a list
index_df1_0 = df1.index[df1['test'] == 0].tolist()

# replace the '0' in df1 with unique values from df1 (assumption #1 imp!)
for val_ in range(len(index_df1_0)):
    df1.iloc[index_df1_0[val_]] = unique_df2.iloc[val_]

print(df1)
```

Comment: Thanks swphsil. sorry for my late reply..

Comment: No problem stvlam22.